# Undefined reference to std::to_string while linking

Tags: cross-compiling, openwrt, uclibc

I am trying to cross-compile a program with uClibc and I am always getting an error with undefined reference to std::to_string while linking is performed. I already applied the workaround, which should help to solve this issue:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

template <typename T>
std::string to_string(T value)
{
    std::ostringstream os ;
    os << value ;
    return os.str() ;
}

int main()
{
     std::string perfect = to_string(5) ;
}
```

This helped in the phase of building CXX objects, but while linking the problem is back.

Here is the error:

```
[ 76%] Linking CXX executable gateway
 /home/jakub/build/openwrt/staging_dir/target-arm_cortex-a9+vfpv3_uClibc- 
0.9.33.2_eabi/usr/lib/libPocoFoundation.so: warning: the use of OBSOLESCENT `utime' is discouraged, use 
`utimes'
/home/jakub/build/openwrt/staging_dir/target-arm_cortex-a9+vfpv3_uClibc- 
0.9.33.2_eabi/usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: warning: gethostbyname is obsolescent, use getnameinfo() instead.
libGateway.a(NewDeviceCommand.cpp.o): In function `Gateway::NewDeviceCommand::toString() const':
NewDeviceCommand.cpp:(.text+0x218): undefined reference to `std::to_string(int)'
libGateway.a(DeviceManager.cpp.o): In function `Gateway::DeviceManager::lastValue(Gateway::DeviceID 
const&, Gateway::ModuleID const&, Poco::Timespan const&)':
DeviceManager.cpp:(.text+0x554): undefined reference to `std::to_string(int)'
DeviceManager.cpp:(.text+0x57c): undefined reference to `std::to_string(unsigned long)'
libGateway.a(DeviceManager.cpp.o): In function 
`Gateway::DeviceManager::responseDeviceList(Poco::Timespan const&, 
Poco::AutoPtr<Gateway::Answer>)':
DeviceManager.cpp:(.text+0xc04): undefined reference to `std::to_string(unsigned long)'
DeviceManager.cpp:(.text+0xc2c): undefined reference to `std::to_string(unsigned long)'
DeviceManager.cpp:(.text+0xce0): undefined reference to `std::to_string(unsigned long)'
DeviceManager.cpp:(.text+0xd08): undefined reference to `std::to_string(unsigned long)'
....
```

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: are you linking with the correct version of libstdc++?

Comment: I am using the flag -std=c++11.